how to use css variables to contain color-mix used with another variable
I have in css (generated by sass) variable called --secondary and it's value is red(#f00)
I want to create more variables for opacity like --secondary-100, --secondary-90, ...
I used color-mix in oklab, so this is the code:


setTimeout(_ => {
  document.querySelector('div').style.cssText += `--secondary:#f00;`
},100)
div { 
  width:100px;
  height:100px;

  --secondary-100: color-mix(in oklab, var(--secondary) 100%, transparent 0%);
  background-color: var(--secondary-100);
}
<div></div>



as you can see the div is transparent not red
( if you see it red that mean i didn't recreate the problem the problem stile exist in the real firefox site )
i tried it in firefox and this is the result


in devtools i just wrote the same thing contains in the variable --secondary-100 out of it
and it suddenly works idk where is the problem or is it a well known problem and I'm living under my rock
btw this variables and colors is user choice and not static so i can't just write them my self and the best i can do is to use javascript to deal with those colors and save them directly without using color-mix

Does this answer your question? How to create color shades using CSS variables similar to darken() of Sass?

no i doesn't because the javascript changes the colors so i just use normal css variables not compiled with sass

The top answer is a CSS-only solution. Unsure where you're seeing SASS ?

no the same problem it works if i right it as a value to the background property directly but if it's inside another variable it doesn't work for some reason but good suggestion

it was new to me as if it's a magic so i assumed it was something to do with sass

i will just scrap the idea until i solve it
it's hard to even explain it

You have to specify the method parameter. It is the first parameter.


div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  --secondary: #f00;
  --secondary-100: color-mix(in srgb, var(--secondary) 100%, transparent 0%);
  background-color: var(--secondary-100);
}
<div></div>




i just forget it in this code example but i didn't work

It just worked when I replaced the :root with *.
I don’t know why or how, but in Chrome dev tools, it appears that the variable declared in the :root wasn't declared in the children.
